# Como usar o Order By antes do Union no sql Server usando essa query?

Tags: sql-server

Eu tenho essa query:

```
    SELECT * FROM (

SELECT distinct
        db_name() as 'Banco_de_Dados',g.KM_SIMBOL, fotos = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.globalid ORDER BY d.globalid),d.GDB_FROM_DATE as Data , g.RODOVIA , g.CODIGO 
    FROM [dbo].GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO d
        INNER JOIN [dbo].GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO__ATTACH a
    ON a.REL_GLOBALID = d.GlobalID
        INNER JOIN GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL  g
    ON D.vertical_rel_globalid= G.VERTICAL_GLOBALID


                 ) d 


    WHERE fotos > 2
    order by d.Data

        UNION  --USEI UNION PARA JUNTAR O RESULTADO DE UM MESMO BANCO DE DADOS

    SELECT * FROM (
SELECT distinct
         db_name() as 'Banco_de_Dados',g.KM_SIMBOL, fotos = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.globalid ORDER BY d.globalid),d.GDB_FROM_DATE as Data , g.RODOVIA , g.CODIGO 
    FROM [dbo].GO_35_BR070_TREVOGIRASSOL_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO d
        INNER JOIN [dbo].GO_35_BR070_TREVOGIRASSOL_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO__ATTACH a
    ON a.REL_GLOBALID = d.GlobalID 
        INNER JOIN GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL  g 
    ON D.vertical_rel_globalid= G.VERTICAL_GLOBALID


                  ) d

    WHERE fotos > 2
    order by d.Data
```

QUANDO EU USO DESSE JEITO O "UNION" FICA SUBLIMADO EM VERMELHO SINALIZANDO QUE HÁ ERRO. Mas se tirar o UNION a minha query funciona sem problema.Alguém para me ajudar?

Comment: porque você precisa ordenar antes do _union_?

Comment: Tire o _d.data_ do _order by_. Use:    `order by data`

Comment: @rLinhares para filtrar a  primeira query e depois juntar  a segunda query usando Union

Comment: @WesleyFerreira mesmo se eu tirar isso não vai mudar nada caro amigo :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então veja se englobando tudo em outro select e incluindo uma coluna de ordenação resolve:

```
Select * from 
(
        SELECT * FROM (
                        SELECT distinct
                                1 as ordem,            
                                db_name() as 'Banco_de_Dados',g.KM_SIMBOL, fotos = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.globalid),d.GDB_FROM_DATE as Data , g.RODOVIA , g.CODIGO 
                        FROM [dbo].GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO d
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO__ATTACH a
                        ON a.REL_GLOBALID = d.GlobalID
                        join GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL  g ON D.vertical_rel_globalid= G.VERTICAL_GLOBALID
                        ) d 
        WHERE fotos > 2

        UNION  --USEI UNION PARA JUNTAR O RESULTADO DE UM MESMO BANCO DE DADOS

        SELECT * FROM (
                        SELECT distinct
                        2 as ordem,
                        db_name() as 'Banco_de_Dados',g.KM_SIMBOL, fotos = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.globalid ),d.GDB_FROM_DATE as Data , g.RODOVIA , g.CODIGO 
                        FROM [dbo].GO_35_BR070_TREVOGIRASSOL_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO d
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].GO_35_BR070_TREVOGIRASSOL_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO__ATTACH a
                        ON a.REL_GLOBALID = d.GlobalID 
                        join GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL  g ON D.vertical_rel_globalid= G.VERTICAL_GLOBALID
                        ) d    
        WHERE fotos > 2
        ) a 
Order by Ordem, Data
```

Comment: o meu problema não é isso exatamente, pois usando o Over com count funciona sim. se eu tirar esse union ele funciona sem problema. Mas colocando o union da erro.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, coloquei uma coluna de ordenação nos 2 selects e envolvi com outro select colocando o order by somente nele.

Comment: valeu @Alexandre mas corrigi o que você fez. não é que está errado. o que você fez está certo só que faltou um pequeno detalhe pra isso rodar.eu vou postar a correção e explicando o que fiz – Gladiador 1 hora atrás

Answer (score 0):

Para corrigir eu simplesmente adicionei o a na frente do Order By que está nesse código que o nosso amigo @Alexandre Cavaloti mandou para mim aqui. o

> "a"

é a referência para a tabela com "ATTACH"no primeiro select como para o segundo select.

```
 Select * from 
    (
            SELECT * FROM (
                            SELECT distinct
                                    1 as ordem,            
                                    db_name() as 'Banco_de_Dados',g.KM_SIMBOL, fotos = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.globalid),d.GDB_FROM_DATE as Data , g.RODOVIA , g.CODIGO 
                            FROM [dbo].GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO d
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO__ATTACH a
                            ON a.REL_GLOBALID = d.GlobalID
                            join GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL  g ON D.vertical_rel_globalid= G.VERTICAL_GLOBALID
                            ) d 
            WHERE fotos > 2

            UNION  --USEI UNION PARA JUNTAR O RESULTADO DE UM MESMO BANCO DE DADOS

            SELECT * FROM (
                            SELECT distinct
                            2 as ordem,
                            db_name() as 'Banco_de_Dados',g.KM_SIMBOL, fotos = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.globalid ),d.GDB_FROM_DATE as Data , g.RODOVIA , g.CODIGO 
                            FROM [dbo].GO_35_BR070_TREVOGIRASSOL_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO d
                                INNER JOIN [dbo].GO_35_BR070_TREVOGIRASSOL_PE_VERTICAL_MANUTENCAO__ATTACH a
                            ON a.REL_GLOBALID = d.GlobalID 
                            join GO_35_BR070_PE_VERTICAL  g ON D.vertical_rel_globalid= G.VERTICAL_GLOBALID
                            ) d    
            WHERE fotos > 2
            )a



    Order by Ordem, Data
```

Comment: É verdade, fiz essa correção no meu select local mas não tinha colocado no exemplo do código. Vou ajustar na solução acima também.

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti valeu meu amigo.você ajudou muito!